# Multiple admob account ads in app

Tags: android, google-play, admob

My question is about showing ads from multiple accounts. 
If me and a other persoon created an app and we Both have An admob accounts. 
Can we put Both our ads inside the same app or is this a violation?

I cant seem to find an answer on the admob website.